# Can I apply both differentiation on lag 2 and two differentiations on a time-series?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, lags, differences

I'm working with time-series and I have seem two approaches from different teachers. One of them used the following code in Python:

```
import pandas as np
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
diff_2 = np.diff(np.diff(df['column']))
```

and the other used:

```
diff_lag2 = df['column'].diff(2)
```

The first is applying differentiation twice on a serie. The second is applying differentiation with two lags. You can see more about these techniques in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Both used these approaches to make a serie stationary. Are both correct?
Also, since we are on this subject, would it be ok to apply any of these approaches after detrending a serie?

I think we can summarise the two questions with: are all transformations valid to make a serie stationary?

Bear in mind that df is something like this:

```
date          column
2020-01-01    100
2020-02-01    112
2020-03-01    130
2020-04-01    128
.
.
.
```